# Calling method of the base class (not the immediate parent class)

Tags: inheritance, coffeescript

Let's say I have 3 classes that inherit one another and all override the same method:

```
class Base
    foo: ->
      console.log 'base'

class Middle extends Base
    foo: ->
      console.log 'middle'

class Child extends Middle
    foo: ->
      console.log 'child'
```

If I need to call `Middle`'s implementation from `Child`, I can use `super`. But what if I need to call `Base`'s implementation? Does coffescript support that?

Comment: Not as far as I know. You could pass a flag to `Middle.foo()` to tell it to return `Base.foo()` ... But, more importantly, are you sure this is what you really want? If `Child` inherits from `Middle` but wants to call `foo` on `Base`, then perhaps `Child` should not inherit from `Middle`? Or maybe you shouldn't override `foo` at all but make separate functions? In my experience, using this sort of inheritance and function overriding too much can lead to some pretty confusing code!

Comment: I agree that this is bad design. I have organization's  business logic represented as a dozen of coffescript classes inheriting one another. Mixins would be perfect for this kind of inheritance, but coffescript doesn't have them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit ugly, but this is possible:

```
class Child extends Middle
  foo: ->
    console.log 'child'
    @constructor.__super__.constructor.__super__.foo()
```

I don't know if it can be shorter.

Comment: This doesn't work in my particular case because I need to access `Child`'s instance variables, but good to know.

Comment: This is the answear to your question. You may ask a new question with your variables problem.